# How to make this regex

Tags: regex

I don't know how to make this regex, do you have an idea ?

I want to match these strings

> 1234
>
> 1234-1
>
> 1234-12

First part is obvious

```
[0-9]{4}
```

But the second part is the problem

```
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{0,2}
```

This can't work because I don't want to match

> 1234-

To resume, I need to merge these 2 regex into one

```
[0-9]{4}
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Use an optional group which consists of `-[0-9]{1,2}`

Comment: How would you do that ? I'm also wondering if the fact the character is `-` isn't a problem considering it's part on the regex syntax

Comment: `-[0-9]{1,2}` => `(?:-[0-9]{1,2})?`, it is a long solved issue.

Comment: Ok thanks guys, I really didn't knew about it at all :/

Comment: @Kurano `-` does not have a special meaning in regex unless it's inside a character class (square brackets): `[0-9]` uses a special meaning for `-`, but `mother-in-law` will just be considered a straight literal match.